# if image width > 400 = image width = 100% css

Tags: css

I'd like to check if an image width has more than 400px I'd like this image to get full div width. if image is less than 400px just print it in its normal size.

any ideas how to do this?

```
<div id="volta">
<img src="/img/volta.jpg">
</div>
```

---

```
#volta{
 width:500px;
}
```

Comment: This is very easy to do with jQuery. I won't comment further on this, however, since you only tagged this post with CSS.

Comment: do you know the width of the image before hand? or is it dynamic?

Comment: Not exactly how you specified but setting `max-width: 100%` on the img would allow it to resize with the container without stretching larger than its natural size if that is your concern: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/2yrgznkq/3/

Comment: @ibu user can send an image, it may has any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply an id to the image, and with jquery check its width
If it is greather than 400px modify his width or add a class that does the same.

Example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  if($("#image").width() > 400){
     $("#image").css("width", "100%");
  }
  else{
    $("#image").css("width", "10px");
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id = "image" src = "https://pm1.narvii.com/6919/98f453834b5d87a6c92118da9c24fe98e1784f6ar1-637-358v2_hq.jpg"/>
```

Comment: my problem is that I have many divs with images to check, not only one. `<div class="volta"><img src="/img.jpg" class="voltaimg"></div><div class="volta"><img src="/img.jpg2" class="voltaimg"></div><div class="volta"><img src="/img.jpg3" class="voltaimg"></div>`... and more can be load dinamically when user scroll down the page.

Comment: In that case, what if you add a class to the images and then with jquery do a for each that affects every image, $.each(".image", function(i, image){if($(this).width() > 400{do something})}), and when the new images appear just execute that code again

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this does not exist in CSS. What you should do instead is use classes.

Define some CSS class that applies the styles you want:

```
.long_width {
background: blue;
}
```

Then you would use Javascript to check the width of the image. You don't need jQuery to do this you can do it in vanilla Javascript (unless you already have jQuery imported and need it for other things). Maybe something like this:

```
let elm = document.querySelector('[src="/img/volta.jpg]"');
let width = window.getComputedStyle(elm).getPropertyValue('width');
```

And then you would use Javascript to add and remove styles accordingly:

```
if (width > 400) {
elm.classList.add("long_width");
}
else {
elm.classList.remove("long_width");
}
```

The specific answer to your question depends on what your intentions are. But to keep your code simple, you should use Javascript to handle the logic and not depend on CSS selectors for things this complicated. Instead, create a CSS class that contains the styles you need, and then use Javascript to apply it based on the size of the user uploaded image.

Additionally, if the user uploads the image, you should load it into memory and check its attributes in memory rather than by depending on a DOM element. Something like:

```
let img = new Image();
img.src = "{data URL of img}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need javascript / jQuery to work. Something like this:

```js
$('img').each(function(){
  if($(this).width() > 400){
    $(this).css('width', '100%');
  }
});
```

Here is also [working jquery example](http://jsfiddle.net/rw48xcjy/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like FlokiTheFisherman (with %), or you can use "wv" instead of "%".
I recommend using vw.

Answer (score 0):

```
img[width='400'] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But it's attribute selector. Will it work without explicit `width` attribute?

Comment: No it will not.